# MySQL - Select lowest price that has quantity, if none have quantity, select the lowest price

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have a table with product_id, warehouse, quantity, and price. My goal is to select the lowest price for each product. However, I want to choose the record with the lowest price that has a quantity, unless they are all 0 in which case I want the record with just the lowest price.

**Example**

| product_id | warehouse | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 | 14 |
| 1 | B | 0 | 12 |
| 1 | C | 8 | 17 |
| 2 | A | 0 | 12 |
| 2 | C | 0 | 10 |
| 3 | D | 3 | 12 |

After the query, it should return a table such as this:

| product_id | warehouse | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 | 14 |
| 2 | C | 0 | 10 |
| 3 | D | 3 | 12 |

My initial thought is to do some kind of inner join on price = min(price). I know how to get the record with the min price but can't wrap my brain around having it dependent on the quantity as well.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY NOT quantity, quantity, price)`

Comment: @Akina Works great! Thank you! My final statement looks like this: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY NOT quantity, quantity, price) AS row_num FROM prices) t1 WHERE row_num = 1` Is that how to use it correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. One point - `quantity` must have no NULL values.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I just adjusted the table to add `NOT NULL` and `DEFAULT 0` to `quantity`